# Unable to Install Ubuntu (Compiz Unresponsive I believe)

Tags: ati, compiz, system-installation, ubiquity

Heyoh, little bit of a linux veteran but I've never run into this before. I just got a new Desktop PC and it has Windows 7 on it. I'm looking to dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 on this set up but I keep running into an issue in the live environment.

I can open windows (like gparted or firefox) and even start ubiquity. But ubiquity will become unresponsive before getting partitioning to start.

The real issue or what I believe is the source of the problem is that all the compiz elements of my screen are unresponsive. I can switch windows with keyboard but as far as clicking window titlebars to drag windows or using the Max, Min, and Close buttons nothing works. I can't even click the shutdown buttons in the top right. To reboot I have to switch the X display and run Sudo Reboot.

My Hardware is as follows:

- ATI Radeon HD 7850 Graphics Card
- 8 GB of Crucial Ballistix RAM
- AMD 6100 Bulldozer Processor
- And an ASRock Motherboard I can't       remember the make/model and
  the box is not around any longer.

I am also running dual monitors if that is relevant.

If you need more information or the results of any linux commands I may be able to fenangle them into the post with keyboard fu and I would be more than happy to try.

Answer (score 0):

with a fresh build and install problems always occur. I found it most helpful to tackle them singularly! use single monitor plugged into board VGA or DVI socket. also my Asrocks motherboard only checks the board mounted USB on start up.and does NOT recognize a USB keyboard.

Comment: Do you think an older build would work? Like if I went to 13.04 and then upgraded?